# How to enable digest when building libcurl

Tags: c++, c, linux, curl, libcurl

I build libcurl and run it but it doesnot works when server require digest authentication.

I checked the C code  and I found that the following part (in http.c in output_auth_headers function) is not build:

```
#ifndef CURL_DISABLE_CRYPTO_AUTH
  if(authstatus->picked == CURLAUTH_DIGEST) {
    auth="Digest";
    result = Curl_output_digest(conn,
                                proxy,
                                (const unsigned char *)request,
                                (const unsigned char *)path);
    if(result)
      return result;
  }
  else
#endif
```

What I should do to make this part of the code building and then make the digest running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When configuring, make sure to select `--enable-crypto-auth`.

Like so:

```
./buildconf && ./configure --enable-crypto-auth
```